# Вывести текст из h2 js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему при клике на кнопку не выводит текст h2?

```js
 <script>
    function action_but(code, ttl){
     
     var selects = {}
       
     $(".constructor .result_category form input[type=hidden]").each(function(){
            selects[$(this).attr("name")]=$(this).val();
        });
     
    }
    
    
     $(".constructor .result_category .ln").click(function(){
      $(this).find(".get_list").click();
      
      return false;
     });
     
     $(".constructor .result_category .add").click(function(){
      var code = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
      var ttl = $(this).parent("h2").text();
      
      alert(ttl);
      
      return false;
     });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="ln">
 <input type="hidden" name="{$id | resource : 'idcategory'}" value>
 <div class="data_img">
  <img src="{$id | resource : 'iconcategory'}" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="data_footer">
  <h2 class="name">{$id | resource : 'ncategory'}</h2>
  <p>{$id | resource : 'description'}</p>
  <div class="btn_box flex">
   <a href="#{$id | resource : 'idcategory'}" class="button add get_list">Выбрать</a>
   <a href="#{$id | resource : 'idcategory'}" class="button hidden remove">Удалить</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ttl = $(this).closest(".data_footer").find("h2").text();
```

```js
$(".add").click(function() {
  var ttl = $(this).closest(".data_footer").find("h2").text();
  alert(ttl);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ln">
  <input type="hidden" name="{$id | resource : 'idcategory'}" value>
  <div class="data_img">
    <img src="{$id | resource : 'iconcategory'}" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="data_footer">
    <h2 class="name">{$id | resource : 'ncategory'}</h2>
    <p>{$id | resource : 'description'}</p>
    <div class="btn_box flex">
      <a href="#{$id | resource : 'idcategory'}" class="button add get_list">Выбрать</a>
      <a href="#{$id | resource : 'idcategory'}" class="button hidden remove">Удалить</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```